# Update GUI upon button Click: JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, javafx, platform

Looking to update GUI first thing upon click of a button however Platform.runLater executes at a later stage and am looking for the piece of code which updates the GUI to happen first thing upon click of a button.

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Update GUI here
                    }
                });
```

Would highly appreciate if anyone can provide any inputs or recommendations.

Comment: Why are you using `Platform.runLater(...)` at all?

Comment: To be able to update GUI on a GUI thread, Please let me know for a better recommendation.

Comment: The event handlers are invoked on the GUI thread anyway.

Comment: However by the time GUI gets updated, it is too late. Would like the GUI to be updated as a first thing

Comment: What do you mean by "update gui"? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Apart from that: Why is it too late? No human being will notice the difference between a direct call and `Platform.runLater(...)` usually.

Comment: By updating the GUI, I mean populating the TableView with values from database. It actually takes few minutes before Platform.runLater(...) executes and by the time the state of database has changed and there is nothing to be displayed.

Comment: What takes a few minutes? Is it a few minutes before `task` in `Platform.runLater(task)` is _started_ or _finished_? It should normally only take a few milliseconds before `task` is started. If `task` takes too long to execute (like querying a remote database), you should not execute it on the UI thread.

Comment: did you mind "validate()"?

Comment: @Tomas: Few minutes before task is started inside Platform.runLater(task)

Comment: Then I wonder what the UI thread is doing in the meantime. Is your UI responsive in the meantime?

Comment: @JohnC Please edit and clarify the question. You original question says nothing about executing long-running database access code, how (or even if) you are using background threads to manage this code, and doesn't fully explain when you want the UI to be updated in relation to the execution of this code. You need to provide enough information for this question to be answered.

Answer (score 2):

Although the API specifies that `Platform.runLater` "runs the specified Runnable on the JavaFX Application Thread at some unspecified time in the future", it usually takes little to no time for the specified thread to be executed. Instead, you can just add an EventHandler to the button to listen for mouse clicks.

Assuming the controller `implements Initializable`

```
    @FXML Button button;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {
        button.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                updateGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateGUI() {
        // code
    }
```

Comment: This code looks strange. Why are you registering a handler inside an `@FXML` annotated method? You are anticipating that there is some event that will occur that will cause the handler to be registered (so that only click on the button *subsequent* to that event will trigger the GUI update)? And why are you using `setOnMouseClicked(...)` instead of `setOnAction(...)` for a `Button`?

Comment: See updated answer. You're right, the method doesn't need to be @FXML; I moved it to `initialize(...)` instead. I left it as `setOnMouseClicked(...)` simply because the question specified **upon click of a button**. I assumed that button here meant an FXML button.